# Why do both Hypergeometric1F1Regularized and Hypergeometric1F1 explode for large x?

Tags: special-functions

Hi I am wondering why the increasing solution to eq0 below explodes for large x. Mathematica presents this as LaguerreL[-1-q,m,x], which is the same thing as a multiple of Hypergeometric1F1. Both functions explode 
at the same point, and this keeps being true for Hypergeometric1F1Regularized . Thanks

```
cn = {q -> 1/6, m -> 1/2};
eq0 = x y''[x] + (x + 1 - m) y'[x] - q y[x]; so = 
DSolve[eq0 == 0, y, x][[1]];
H = y /. so /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> Gamma[-q] /Gamma[m - q]};
Print["H=", H[x]]
Plot[{H[x], 
   Exp[-x] x^m Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[1 + q, 1 + m, x]} /. 
  cn, {x, 0, 800}]
```

Comment: What does "explode" mean here, exactly? What behavior were you expecting? The [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hDtN.png) I get looks tame to me.

Comment: If you take the series of the H function that you have, the leading term goes like x^q. Were you expecting something different? The command I used is quite straightforward/stupid H[x] // Series[#, {x, Infinity, 1}] & // Normal // Expand

Comment: @J.M. It does "explode" around x=749 for Windows 10 Mathematica 12.0.0.0.  But adding in `WorkingPrecision -> 30` fixes that.

Comment: @Jim, looks like a version 12 problem, then. What happens if you evaluate this: `With[{q = 1/6, m = 1/2}, Plot[x^m Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[m - q, 1 + m, - x], {x, 0, 800}]]`?

Comment: @J.M. It looks good.

Comment: I'll write an answer later in the morning, then, unless someone beats me to it.

Comment: Machine precision calculations neither track nor control precision. Consequently, complicated calculations such as those for higher transcendental functions can lose precision and result in the effects that you see. Specifying the `WorkingPrecision` in the `Plot` will result in the use of arbitrary-precision calculations which will track and control the precision. Use `Plot[Evaluate[{H[x], Exp[-x] x^m Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[1+q, 1+m, x]} /. cn], {x, 0, 800}, WorkingPrecision -> 20, PlotStyle -> {Automatic, Dashed}]`

Comment: As mentioned, the leading term  is x^q, and for some reason both the ODE and the direct evaluation exploded at the same point  also for Windows 10,  Mathematica  11.3, (without WorkingPrecision -> ), unless one uses the identity given by J.M.isinlimbo :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function being plotted is

```
FullSimplify[DSolveValue[x y''[x] + (x + 1 - m) y'[x] - q y[x] == 0, y[x], x] /.
             {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> Gamma[-q]/Gamma[m - q]}]
   E^-x x^m Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[1 + q, 1 + m, x]
```

Surprisingly, another `FunctionExpand[]`/`FullSimplify[]` roundtrip gives a different, yet equivalent expression:

```
FullSimplify[FunctionExpand[%]]
   x^m Hypergeometric1F1Regularized[m - q, 1 + m, -x]
```

where the damping `E^-x`factor has already been absorbed into the Kummer hypergeometric function.

One can be transformed into the other through the [Kummer transformation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/13.2.E39) (which is how I initially derived the required expression in the comments). Testing on version 12 in the cloud shows that the latter does not blow up where the former one does.

Answer (score 2):

The result of

```
cq = 1/6; m = 1/2;
eq0 = x y''[x] + (x + 1 - m) y'[x] - q y[x];
so =  AsymptoticDSolveValue[eq0 == 0, y[x], {x, Infinity, 7}];
so /. {C[1] -> 0, C[2] -> Gamma[-q]/Gamma[m - q]}

*(1/Gamma[1/3])E^-x (-(1993326710375/(688747536 x^(23/3))) +
64899009175/(153055008 x^(20/3)) - 103178075/(1417176 x^(17/3)) + 
2377375/(157464 x^(14/3)) - 8645/(2187 x^(11/3)) + 455/(
 324 x^(8/3)) - 7/(9 x^(5/3)) + 1/x^(2/3)) Gamma[-(1/6)]*
```

shows not explosion, but rapid decrease of the solution at infinity.

Comment: Thanks for this useful command! What happens is that C[1] and C[2] are reversed when using AsymptoticDSolveValue; my explosion happens with  
      so = AsymptoticDSolveValue[eq0 == 0, y[x], {x, Infinity, 1}];
      so /. {C[1] -> Gamma[-q]/Gamma[m - q], C[2] -> 0}